# Can't get "count" in "likes" and "comments" fields using my own registered app's access_token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-access-token

**Main Question:**

When I sent a GET request to retrieve data of someID/POSTS, like 
`https://graph.facebook.com/microsoft/posts?fields=comments,likes&limit=1&access_token=`, cannot get the **"count"** in "likes" and "comments" fields using the access token generated by my own facebook registered app, but can get the expected data if using the access token from Facebook Sample apps, e.g. "[HelloFacebookSample](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)".

This issue occurs on both Android and FB Graph API Exploer. Also in oder to troubleshoot the possible causes, I used the exactly same codes as FB sample under my registered app_id, but the same problem came out again. So the only possible explanation I can think of is some strange things with FB app_id, not the permission scopes or different users(I've tested using two users).

Here is, the **Reponses** from GET request of `https://graph.facebook.com/microsoft/posts?fields=likes&limit=1&access_token=`:

1.Using access_token generated by **my app_id**:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
       "id": "20528438720_10151574758413721", 
       "created_time": "2013-07-18T18:41:51+0000", 
       "likes": {
          "data": [
            {
               "id": "701134683", 
               "name": "Someone's name"
            }, 
            {
               "id": "113770258795376", 
               "name": "Someone's name"
            }
            /****and so on****/
        ], 
        "paging": {
         "cursors": {
           "after": "MTAwMDAwNjkxNDMxMTcz", 
           "before": "NzAxMTM0Njgz"
         }, 
         "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/20528438720_10151574758413721/likes?limit=25&after=MTAwMDAwNjkxNDMxMTcz"
       }
     }
   }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/20528438720/posts?fields=likes&limit=1&since=1374172911", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/20528438720/posts?fields=likes&limit=1&until=1374172910"
  }
}
```

2.Using access_token generated by **FB's sample app_id**(here it can get "count" of likes):

```
{
  "data": [
      {
        "likes": {
          "data": [
          {
                "name": "Someone's name", 
              "id": "100003531173993"
            }, 
            {
              "name": "Someone's name", 
              "id": "100002299390558"
            }, 
            {
              "name": "Someone's name", 
              "id": "1038509978"
            }, 
            {
              "name": "Someone's name", 
              "id": "1615491698"
            }
          ], 
        "count": 1071
      }, 
      "id": "20528438720_10151574758413721", 
      "created_time": "2013-07-18T18:41:51+0000"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/20528438720/posts?fields=likes&limit=1&since=1374172911", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/20528438720/posts?fields=likes&limit=1&until=1374172910"
  }
}
```

It really confused me for days, and I've done lots of searches, but cannot find any useful or related info perhaps due to my English:P. Did anyone else face the similar problems?

Thank you for reading.

Any help or alternative solution appreciated! (here, I just want to display the number of likes in my app)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found the solution myself, it is all due to the FB's migration for [the October 2013 Breaking Changes](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/). They change the POST_ID/likes format, but probably as the migration has not been completed yet, so there are some inconsistencies. The following is an official statement that I got from the Facebook Developer Alert.

> POST_ID/likes format will change. Apps will be able to **retrieve all likes on a post (rather than the first 4 as it is today) through paging**. As a result of the functionality update, **the like count will be moved to the summary field**.

So now if you cannot see “count” in “likes” or “comments” field, just follow the steps below:

1. Send a GET request to, let's say `https://graph.facebook.com/microsoft/posts?fields=likes&limit=1&access_token=` and then you get the POST_ID = "id"
2. a new GET request to `https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes?summary=true&access_token=`, then you will find the "total_count" of "likes" in "summary" field.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in bulks? I've used to perform an API call to `/?ids=<csv of ids>&fields=likes` but adding `&summary=true` to that doesn't add anything.